# Child changes the value in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I pass an array from the parent, in the child I receive it through a props and pass it to the state. After that, I need to add a field to the array, I do this in useEffect. But as soon as this goes through, the data also changes in the parent. Why is this happening?

Parent:

```js
<IncomeDrawer values={selectRowData}/>
```

Child:

```js
const [values, setValues] = useState(props.values);

useEffect(() => {
  let newData = values.docSubs;

  function updateTreeTable(data) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      data[i] = { ...data[i], recordIndex: recordIndex };
      recordIndex++;
      if (data[i].hasOwnProperty('children')) {
        updateTreeTable(data[i].children);
      }
    }

  };
  updateTreeTable(newData);

  setValues({ ...values, docSubs: newData })

}, [])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass props into your `child component`, it passes the `reference`. so if you change the value in `child component` which came from `parent`, it will change in both `child and parent`.

To avoid this, you need to `clone` your `props value` into your `child component` before changing it.

In React, actually in `JavaScript`, there are many ways to `clone` object/array

**Using slice function**

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(props.values.slice());
```

**Using Spread Operator**

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([...props.values]);
```

**Using JSON.parse and JSON.stringify function**

```
const [values, setValues] = useState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.values));
```

> There are some other ways to clone your array. you `google` it if you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution might be to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like that:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([...props.values]);
```

**As pointed out by [Khabir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7119904/khabir) the problem is in the [props reference.](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)**

*P.S. Sorry, I didn't comment, but I don't have the necessary reputation.*

Comment: it would be helpful if you explained _why_ this is the answer.

Comment: Well, the spread operator takes in an iterable (e.g an array) and expands it into individual elements. It is usually used to make shallow copies of objects. So basically you work with a brand new copy of your existing array. Therefore when you change something it shouldn't modify the original array. Sorry I didn't include this originally in the answer. Hope this clarifies why I think that might be the solution here.

Comment: No need to be sorry!  I am just suggesting that a good answer contains both the "how" and the "why," and maybe a cite in the documentation for those who want to read more.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Appreciate it.